I want to insert a picture
<img src="../Images/4-sure.png" alt="4-Sure" />
the image does not show

<img src="../Images/4-sure.png" alt="4-Sure" />

I expected the image to show but is not showing. The image is not showing and it has to show but is not and the path is correct but I do not understand why is it not showing. The image is not available

src uses URL, not path.

This question is similar to: img tag not working with relative path in src. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

can you modify the question with your project details and code sample
